# LEDs sing love poems

Tags: story-identification, quotes, poetry

I'm trying to track down the source of a quote that's been sitting in my memory for years. It's all rotted away now, but there were two parts to it, something like:

> "We wrote spells, carved them into a single crystal of silicon, and
>   sliced it with a diamond saw".

This was essentially a very poetic description of computer programming / semiconductor manufacture.

The other quote was something about

> "LEDs winking love poetry to each other after the lights go out."

I've Googled both of these phrases, and variations of them, but no luck. Does anyone recognize them?

Comment: how many years?  the led winking to each other bit might be talking about fiber optics.

Comment: I always imagined it was the referring to the network traffic indicators.

Comment: Sounds like a line from the Technomages of Babylon 5 or Crusade.

Comment: Nothing about spells or programming, but in this John Orne Green [story about cyber girl/boyfriends](http://www.corpse.org/archives/issue_12/hedonism/green.html): "When the lights go out, I watch the orange and red LED's winking softly on the sides of her satin-finish ebony unit rising and falling at her center."

Comment: In *Darwin among the Machines* there is: *Diamond saw blades slice these crystals into wafers on which spells are cast by ultraviolet light*. No mention of love, poetry or LEDs, though.

Comment: @lserni - Is that the one by George Dyson?